# Low parts count and cheap radio modulation (hack)

Tags: radio

I have an embedded electronics project in mind, but will use a different example to explain what I wonder.

Say we have to PCs, each with a sound card which can sample up to 44kHz. How do I get those to talk to each other over radio?  It helps if the antenna need not be huge, but low parts count and low price is most important. Can the audio signal be modulated in some simple way? Are there ICs which already does the major part?

I have a decent understanding of digital logic, but when it comes to analog things I need a lot of advice.

Assume the PCs can do a certain amount of processing of the signal. The sound card is stereo, could that be used for something?  Like use the left channel for data, and the right channel for some kind of modulation shift?

Comment: On the software side, there are tons of radio modem programs for GNU/Linux. As far as I can see, they make the sound card act as a modem and send data to output which is then sent over radio. I don't know of there anything similar for other operating systems, becasue I only saw them in repositories. It seems that there are established standards for transmitting data over radio using PC sound cards.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, yes, I know there are, and I am comfortable with dreaming up all kinds of solutions within the computer. It's the little physical widgets that I want help with. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Nordic Semi [2.4 GHz wireless chips](http://www.nordicsemi.com/index.cfm?obj=menu&act=displayMenu&men=2) are ideal for low-cost wireless audio, they are cheap and easy to use. Sample the audio from the sound card using a suitable MCU and interface it to one of the Nordic chips.

Comment: Sounds very promising. Do you have any canonical source for those for a hobbyist? Like max 10 of them?

Comment: I've bought them from Clere Electronics, the UK distributor, in small quantities, and they are also available from Farnell. Sparkfun sells modules using them that I have used, as well.

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you mean using a suitable MCU?  That I don't get... can't you hook the sound card up almost directly to the Nordic Semi chip? With MCU, do you mean micro controller?

Comment: Those appear to be Bluetooth devices, which take a digital input.